# Android - why I get failed to bounce to type

Tags: android, firebase

Here is my code in mainActivity and I do everything right I saw in tutorial but it doesn't work for me :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView ff;
private Firebase mFire;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    ff = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.f);

    mFire = new Firebase("https://*******.firebaseio.com/");
    mFire.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String dfg= dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            ff.setText(dfg.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Here is my logcat:

```
07-05 16:25:43.630 26144-26144/com.example.freewaresys.blog E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.freewaresys.blog, PID: 26144
                                                                          com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
                                                                              at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)
                                                                              at com.example.freewaresys.blog.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:27)
                                                                              at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45)
                                                                              at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
                                                                              at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                           Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
                                                                           at [Source: java.io.StringReader@424ba000; line: 1, column: 1]
                                                                              at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:575)
                                                                              at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:46)
                                                                              at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11)
                                                                              at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
                                                                              at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
                                                                              at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:181)
                                                                                ... 13 more
07-05 16:25:45.025 26144-26360/com.example.freewaresys.blog E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x62e30eb0 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x63070940 arg=0x0
07-05 16:25:45.026 26144-26360/com.example.freewaresys.blog E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x62e30eb0 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
```

Comment: add your database structure

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mFire.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
           String str = child.getValue(String.class);
           ff.setText(dfg.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

This is because,  you r listening to a value event, the onDataChange method can be called with multiple matching items. So your code should be ready to handle multiple changes. That is , your DataSnapshot object may have multiple children to which change has occured.